# Javascript not updating h1 tag

Tags: javascript, html

I got a form:

```js
function validateForm() {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "hello?????";
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> some text </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"> yes
                        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"> no
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    
    <h1 id="test"> hello </h1>
```

According to all the posts that I've read this should update the content of the h1 tag when I click the submit button. But it doesn't. Why?

Comment: it works but the form will be submitted after that so the change may not be visible for long.

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: Just `return false;` inside your `validateForm()` function to see the change (prevent form submitting).

Comment: If you don’t want the form to submit, then you need to add `return false;` at the end of your function - so that `onsubmit="return validateForm();"` actually has a value it can return further up.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: ohhh okay I get it. it changes the h1 tag, submits the form and then serves a fresh html page. makes sense, thanks :)

Comment: one more question: document.getElementById("q1").value equals 1 even if I don't choose one of the radio buttons. Why is that? (that's why I needed the h1 -> to check what's inside q1)

Answer (score 0):

When you submit this form, empty action attribute. This form will reload current page. And all data in page will reset default.

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="validateForm();return false;">
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working, it is doing the post and rendering the page so you don't see it (the page reload itself or what that it supposed to do after the submit). If you want to do validation or stop the submit you should return false or use preventDefault() on the form.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, however submit input by default refreshes the page. So you need to prevent this by adding return false at the end of your function.

```
function validateForm() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "hello?????";
    return false;
}
```